# Adding only specific text from a file to an array list, part 2 - Java

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files

I hope I can have some great suggestion how I can solve this here:

I have this text file with places and names - name detail indicates the place(s) that the person has visited:

```
Place: New York
Place: London
Place: Paris
Place: Hongkong

1. Name: John
1. Name detail: London
1. Name detail: Paris
1. Name detail: Hongkong

2. Name: Sarah
2. Name detail: London

3. Name: David
3. Name detail: New York
3. Name detail: Paris
```

Here is a part of my code.

```
private ArrayList<Place> places = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Name> names = new ArrayList<>();


public void load(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<Place> place = places;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    int nameCounter = 1;
    int nameDetailCounter = 1;
    String text;

    try {
        while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {     
            if (text.contains("Place:")) {
                text = text.replaceAll("Place:", "");
                places.add(new Place(text));
            } else if (text.contains(nameCounter + ". Name:")) {
                text = text.replaceAll(nameCounter + ". Name:", "");
                names.add(new Name(text, ""));
                nameCounter ++;
            }
                //starting from here!
                else if (text.contains(nameDetailCounter + ". Name detail:")) {
                text = text.replaceAll(nameDetailCounter + ". Name detail:", "");
                for (Name name : names) {
                    Name nameDetails = findName(name.getName());
                    Place placeDetails = findPlace(text);
                    nameDetails.addName(placeDetails);  
                }
                nameDetailCounter ++;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

My idea is to select all "1." from the text file first and add it in the array, continue with all "2." and add it in the array, and so on.

I have tried many ways, but it did not add all Name detail with the beginning of "1." in the array. I appreciate for any new ideas or suggestions, thanks!

Comment: nameDetailCounter is probably not necessary. You're increasing it after you find a result like "1. Name detail: London" so next it will looking for a "2. Name detail: " record even though you're still looking for "1" records. Looks like you don't even need "nameDetailCounter" and can just use your "nameCounter" variable in its place (but not increment in "detail:" scope).

Comment: Thanks for your advice.. I guess I'm still stuck on this problem. I tired for example to place the nameDetailCounter++ in different position, or as you said delete it and use the nameCounter, but it still only shown for "john" all three visited places, and not for Sarah or David. Any sugguestion that I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be better to use a regular expression to extract the digit on the line instead of trying to track/guess it (see below).

This is a tested recreation of your code since you reference some classes that you didn't provide...but this should hopefully help:

```
public static String getMatch(final String pattern, final String content) {
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(content);

    if (m.find()) {
        return m.group(1);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

public static void load(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {

    List<String> places = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> nameDetails = new ArrayList<String>();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

    String text;
    String lastName = "";

    try {

        while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // extract num from start of line or empty if none..
            String num = getMatch("^([0-9]+)\\.", text);

            if (text.contains("Place:")) {
                text = text.replaceAll("Place:", "");
                places.add(text);
            } else if (text.contains(num + ". Name:")) {
                text = text.replaceAll(num + ". Name:", "");
                names.add(text);
                lastName = text;
            } else if (text.contains(num + ". Name detail:")) {
                text = text.replaceAll(num + ". Name detail:", "");
                nameDetails.add(lastName + " had " + text);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    System.out.println("Places:" + places);
    System.out.println("Names:" + names);
    System.out.println("Name Details:" + nameDetails);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a Name class, how about a Traveler class that has `String name` and `List<Place> places`?  You could then have a method `add(Place p)` on the Traveler class.